# How to read specific chunk from file Node JS?

Tags: node.js, readfile

How to read buffer by selecting a start position and end position from file while on streaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It solves my problem [read-chunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-chunk)

Answer (score 0):

you could create a custom writable stream with the writable interface.  But maybe that defeats the whole purpose of a stream...  do you know upfront which positions you need to read or is it random? if do you need scan patterns?

Comment: please do some basic research before asking, but here you go.  please accept my answer. https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/10026630

Comment: ok so you can access the data while writing without having to open a read stream again.   maybe in the mean time do already something else with the data